# Perpendicular vector to axle

Tags: vectors

There are vectors $\vec{a}=[3,-1,4]$, $\vec{b}=[1,1,-2]$. Which $\vec{c}$ is perpendicular to axle $Y$ and satisy conditions: $\vec{c}\cdot\vec{a}=2, \vec{c}\cdot\vec{b}=2$.

I have no idea how to start it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dot product. If the unknwon vector is $<a,b,c>$ and it has to be perp to the y-axis, it follows that $b=0$, but $a$ and $b$ are still "free"
Now use the dot product twice with $<a,0,c>$ with your given vectors where the outcome of the dot product is to be 2 in each case. It gives you two lin. equations in 2 unknowns. Can you solve it from here?